# Why do changes to the Contact Name Highlights Panel not appear?

Tags: lightning, page-layout, detail-page, compact-layout

By default the Contact Page Hightlights Panel shows Title, Account Name, Phone, Email, Contact Owner.  I wanted to shorten this to just Account Name, Phone, Email.  I made my change in the Page Layout screen for the Contact Layout, then did a Save, but I still see the old layout when I refresh the contact page.  What step did I miss?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Lightning Experience, what you see in the Highlights Panel is controlled by the Compact Layout. Go to Setup | Object Manager | Contacts and locate Compact Layouts on the menu, then create a new one to override the System Default one. That should resolve your issue.

Comment: Thank you - I thought the Compact Layout was for mobile only so I never even tried that.